# how to Call controller when click the button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to call a controller when click the button in view.How can I do it in MVC?.

This is my first controller.

```
public ActionResult DetailForm()
{
    graduandModel model = new graduandModel();

    var ceremonyList = _ceremonyService.GetAllCeremonyByDate(DateTime.Now);

    if (ceremonyList.Count == 0)
    {
        return Content("No ceremony can be loaded");
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var c in ceremonyList)
        {
            model.AvailableCeremony.Add(new SelectListItem() { 
                Text = "Ceremony at " + c.ceremony_date.ToString(), 
                Value = c.ceremony_id.ToString() });
        }
        return View(model);
    }               
}
```

This is my view.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ColumnsThree.cshtml";
}

@model graduandModel
@using Nop.Web.Models.Hire;
@using Nop.Web.Framework;
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@using System.Linq;

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ceremony_id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ceremony_id, Model.AvailableCeremony)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name):
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.first_name)       
        </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.middle_name):
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.middle_name)
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_name):
        </td>
        <td >
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.last_name)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.student_id):
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.student_id)  
        </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" id="btnsearchgraduand" name="btnsearch" 
                class="searchbutton" value="@T("Search")" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then When I click the search button I want to check the input data.
Should I write new controller like this

```
public ActionResult CheckDegreeDetails()
{
    graduandModel model = new graduandModel();

    var degreeList = _graduandService.GetGraduandByStudent(
        model.ceremony_id, model.first_name, 
        model.middle_name, model.last_name);
    return View(model);
}
```

Or...

I don't know how to call controller when click the button...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to wrap your user input fields and the submit button in a form.  You can use an html helper that will also let you specify the controller action to call.
So modify your view:

```
...
@model graduandModel
@using Nop.Web.Models.Hire;
@using Nop.Web.Framework;
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@using System.Linq;

@using(Html.BeginForm("DetailForm", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"})
{
<table  >

 <tr>
    <td >
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ceremony_id)
    </td>
...

//code omitted for brevity

...

<input type="submit" id="btnsearchgraduand" name="btnsearch" class="searchbutton" value="@T("Search")" />

})
```

Then in your controller you need to add the method to 'catch' this form.  You're already using a strongly typed view so capturing the data is easy

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DetailForm (graduandModel model)
{
//do what you need to do with the data here
//the model passed into this method's parameter should 
//contain all the data from the editor templates in the view
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have your button, it won't make the request.

You can use jQuery/javascript. 
HTML:

Javascript:

```
function callController()
{
 $.get("YourController/Action",data, callBackMethod);

}
```

Or you can wrap your input, buttons etc... using [@using(Html.BeginForm(..))](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/mvc-and-posting-data-using-html-beginform-and-url-routing/)